# Is it possible to link to an articles edit-view in joomla 3.0?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

Pretty much as the header states. Can I create a link to an article to edit it. It also has to be visible only to registered users.

Comment: Where do you want to publish this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "external URL":

```
http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=article.edit&a_id=24
```

where 24 is the articles' id.  The user needs to be logged in, and the default behaviour for non logged-in users is to show the category view;

Should this not be desireable, you can get away with writing a simple controller task to handle proper redirection, passing the return url to the login task.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use a link such as http://mysite.com/?view=form&layout=edit&a_id=37, I assume due to security tokens.

You have not described how you'd like the links to look. If it's just to simplify access to articles that are spread all over the site, you could create an article overview page that contains a list of all the articles you want your user to be able to edit. The list items will then have the usual edit button.